# How to change variable during for-loop

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I ran into a problem with a for-loop in js. Let me try to explain my issue.

For example, we have an array

`let arr = [15, 29, 44];`

also we have a `for` loop

```
for (let h = 1; h < 100; h +=10) {
 
}
```

I need to iterate over an array inside the loop, so when `h` goes bigger than array it continues from the value number.

In the end I should get values like: `10, 15, 25, 35, 44, 54...`

I'm trying to make a double loop, but it confuses me.

My code:

```
for (let h = 1; h < 100; h +=10) {
 for (var i = 0; i < arr .length; i++) {
   if(i > h) {
h=i;    
}
}
}
```

Does there better way to do it?

UPD. Sorry, tha arry should be `let array = [{'key': 15}, {'key':29}, {'key':44}];`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a single loop with a check if `h` is greater than a value from the array, then take this value instead.

```js
const
    data = [{ key: 15 }, { key: 29 }, { key: 44 }],
    result = [];

for (let h = 10, i = 0; h < 100; h +=10) {
    if (h > data[i]?.key) h = data[i++].key;
    result.push(h);
}

console.log(...result);
```

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake: it should be an object array `let array = [{'key': 15}, {'key':29}, {'key':44}];`  How to do it in that way?